# Error in highcharts-export-server with expressjs

Tags: node.js, rest, express, highcharts, export

I am trying to create a REST API for exporting Highcharts using node and express. Below is my code,

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const chartExporter = require("highcharts-export-server");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 1200;

app.post('/chart', function(req, res){
    console.log("Json Body from the post request\n", req.body);
    chartExporter.initPool();
    chartExporter.export(res.body, function(error, response){
        console.log("Error from the function", error);
        var imageb64 = response.data;
        console.log("Image From the exporter\n", imageb64);
    });
    chartExporter.killPool();
    console.log("\nPool Killed");
    return "Server Returns successfully!";
});

module.exports = app;
```

Chart Options are below, which is passed as body of the API,

```
{
   "type": "png",
   "options": {
       "chart": {
           "type": "pie"
       },
       "title": {
           "text": "Heading of Chart"
       },
       "plotOptions": {
           "pie": {
               "dataLabels": {
                   "enabled": true,
                   "format": "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}"
               }
           }
       },
       "series": [
           {
               "data": [
                   {
                       "name": "a",
                       "y": 100
                   },
                   {
                       "name": "b",
                       "y": 20
                   },
                   {
                       "name": "c",
                       "y": 50
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error If I run the API,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'svg' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports [as export] (D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\lib\chart.js:270:23)
    at D:\Dev\hc-export-server\server.js:60:22
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at D:\Dev\hc-export-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
```

But If i run the same set of codes separately outside of the API (lets say in the same file), I am getting the response back from the exporter function. Like below. The response is getting printed in the terminal.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const chartExporter = require("highcharts-export-server");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 1200;

const chartDetails = {
   "type": "png",
   "options": {
       "chart": {
           "type": "pie"
       },
       "title": {
           "text": "Heading of Chart"
       },
       "plotOptions": {
           "pie": {
               "dataLabels": {
                   "enabled": true,
                   "format": "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}"
               }
           }
       },
       "series": [
           {
               "data": [
                   {
                       "name": "a",
                       "y": 100
                   },
                   {
                       "name": "b",
                       "y": 20
                   },
                   {
                       "name": "c",
                       "y": 50
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
};
chartExporter.initPool();
chartExporter.export(chartDetails, function(error, response){
        var imageb64 = response.data;
        console.log("Image From the exporter\n", imageb64);
    });
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server started at port ",  port);
});

app.post('/chart', function(req, res){
    console.log("Json Body from the post request\n", req.body);
    chartExporter.initPool();
    chartExporter.export(res.body, function(error, response){
        console.log("Error from the function", error);
        var imageb64 = response.data;
        console.log("Image From the exporter\n", imageb64);
    });
    chartExporter.killPool();
    console.log("\nPool Killed");
    return "Server Returns successfully!";
});

module.exports = app;
```

How do I make it work in the REST API? Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made two mistakes:

- instead of `res.body` you should use `req.body`
- `chartExporter.killPool()` should be inside `chartExporter.export` method callback

---

Correct code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const chartExporter = require("highcharts-export-server");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 1200;

app.post('/chart', function(req, res){
    console.log("Json Body from the post request\n", req.body);
    chartExporter.initPool();
    chartExporter.export(req.body, function(error, response){
        console.log("Error from the function", error);
        var imageb64 = response.data;
        console.log("Image From the exporter\n", imageb64);
        chartExporter.killPool();
        process.exit(1);

        res.send(imageb64);
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```